# Simplification - Pre Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $$\frac{x^4+2x}{x^4}$$ which becomes $$\frac{x^3+2}{x^3}$$ after pulling out the common factor.  I wanted to know why you you don't simplify $\frac{x^4+2x}{x^4}$ to $2x$ and the two $x^4$ cancel each other out, or is this because you must apply the denominator fraction to all numerator parts?  So $\frac{x^4}{x^4}$ and $\frac{2x}{x^4}$ which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do

$$\frac{x^4+2x}{x^4} = \frac{x(x^3+2)}{x(x^3)} = \frac{x^3+2}{x^3}$$

and then split the fraction as

$$\frac{x^3+2}{x^3} = \frac{x^3}{x^3} + \frac{2}{x^3} = 1 + \frac{2}{x^3}$$

Alternatively, split up first, and cancel common factors:

$$\frac{x^4+2x}{x^4} = \frac{x^4}{x^4} + \frac{2x}{x^4} = 1 + \frac{2}{x^3}$$

Either way works, though the second is quicker and a bit more straightforward.

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't cancel the common factor of $x^4$?  Which would just leave me with 2x?

Comment: There is no common factor of $x^4$. You might want to review how to add fractions to see why.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you should imagine that parentheses encompass the entire numerator and whatever happens to it (in this case simplification) must be done to the two terms individually. Then find the greatest common factor for all three terms (it would be "x") and divide the three terms by that.

$${(x^4 + 2x)\over x^4} \to \text{$ cancel\,GCF\,\to$}
{(x^3+2)\over x^3}\to {change\,to\,mixed\,number\,(optional)}\to{1}{2\over x^3}$$